# Prevent Wordpress from adding linebreaks to javascript embedded in a page

Tags: pages, javascript, html-editor

On a page in Wordpress, If I enter the following code:

```
var r='<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
```

it is rendered in the browser as

```
  var r='
<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>

';
```

and it gives me this error in FF Console `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal var r='`

This is a single-user blog, so I am "Administrator".

How do I prevent Wordpress from fouling my code?

Comment: Unless I see a better answer in a couple of days, I'll self-answer that the solution is a plugin that overrides WP default filtering. I used "Text Control" [Found here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/wiki/TextControl)

Comment: I have posted a solution for this issue here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237636/31140

Answer (score 6):

In the new WordPress (WP 5+) Editor - Gutenberg, you can use a  "Custom HTML" block to prevent the automatic line breaks and paragraphs:

on Visual Editor click + > Formatting > Custom HTML - and put your JavaScript in there

on Code Editor enclose your JavaScript with `<!-- wp:html --> <!-- /wp:html -->`

Comment: The typical approach to disabling wpautop (removing the filter) wasn't working for me for some reason. This seems to get the job done! 

Answer (score 4):

**The Problem**

Really annoying! WordPress `wpautop` parses the whole page and adds line-breaks in HTML code after certain tags.
Unfortunately WP does not recognize when HTML strings occur inside javascript and this can mess up the JS source code of your page!!

```
// This breaks your JS code:
<script>
json={"html":"<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>"};
</script>

// After wpautop is done with your code it becomes invalid JSON/JS:
<script>
json={"html":"<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
</ul>"};
</script>
```

---

**★★ Easy solution ★★**

`wpautop` has a small exception built in: It will not add line breaks inside `<pre></pre>` blocks :) We can use this to our advantage, simply by wrapping our `<script>` tags with `<pre>`:

```
// Simple solution!
<pre><script>
json={"html":"<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>"};
</script></pre>

// Extra: Add |style| to ensure the empty <pre> block is not rendered:
<pre style="display:none"><script>
json={"html":"<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>"};
</script>
```

Comment: So grateful for the caveat! Of course we would've thought the nut who wrote wpautop would've done the same for <script> and <style> tags, esp. considering wpautop runs after shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bracket the function in `<script>` tags and then either

1) take all the whitespace out of the script so WordPress does not add `<p>` tags and then the JS will work, or

2) disable `autop` in the post editor for all posts/pages
(see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop ) so WP doesn't add paragraph breaks, or

3) do the following, which leaves `autop` enabled globally, but lets you disable it with  and  tags in individual posts and pages.

**Add the function below to functions.php and use the two tags**

`<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->`

**in your page/post editor, i.e.**

```
    text will be rendered *with* autop

    <!-- noformat on -->

    text will be rendered *without* autop

    <!-- noformat off -->

    text will be rendered *with* autop
```

Content outside of the two format tags will have autop enabled, as noted.

**Add to functions.php of the theme:**

```
// <!-- noformat on --> and <!-- noformat off --> functions

function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```

Comment: I thought "<script>" was obvious but it's still good info for future readers.

Comment: Awesome solution :) Something like this should make it into core...

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of `newautop` adapted from above:

```
function toggleable_autop($text, $filter_state = 'autop_enabled') {
    /* Each tag is associated with the key that will toggle the state from current */
    $filter_driver = [
        'autop_enabled' => [ 'tag' => '<!-- noformat on -->', 'filter' => function($text) { return convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($text))); } ],
        'autop_disabled'  => [ 'tag' => '<!-- noformat off -->', 'filter' => function($text) { return $text; } ],
    ];

    if ( strlen($text) === 0 ) {
        return '';
    }

    $end_state_position = strpos($text, $filter_driver[$filter_state]['tag']);
    if ( $end_state_position === false ) {
        $end_state_position = strlen($text);
    }
    return $filter_driver[$filter_state]['filter'](substr($text, 0, $end_state_position))
        . toggleable_autop(
            substr($text, $end_state_position + strlen($filter_driver[$filter_state]['tag'])),
            $filter_state === 'autop_enabled' ? 'autop_disabled' : 'autop_enabled'
        );
}
```